# "AIRMap" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I followed the instruction in the documentation for installing `react-native-maps`. I also tried every answer I could find online.
Please help me !!

I've tried every solution my hands can find, and still no answer. I'll be glad if someone can help me fix this.
Below is what my code looks like:

```
<MapView
       provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
       style={styles.map}
       region={{
         latitude: params.latitude,
         longitude:params.longitude,
         latitudeDelta: 0.015,
         longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
       }}
     >
        <Marker coordinate={{ latitude:params.latitude, longitude: params.longitude }}
        pinColor={colors.orange}
        > 
        </Marker>
     </MapView>
```

Answer (score -2):

try to re-build the project after installing

> react-native-maps

.
it works for me .

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).